# Debian wheezy to jessie update hangs during boot - setting up x socket directories... /tmp/.x11-unix /tmp/.ice-unix

Tags: debian, debian-wheezy

I have windows 7 as host and debian 7 as guest in vmware.

I was trying to upgrade to debian jessie according to this article
https://www.rootusers.com/how-to-upgrade-debian-7-wheezy-to-debian-8-jessie/

I followed the steps up to changing the source list and making `apt-get upgrade`. It was fine. Just before making `apt-get dist-upgrade` I decided to reboot. Now I can not continue, because during booting it hangs up on this line

`setting up x socket directories... /tmp/.x11-unix /tmp/.ice-unix`

I had without gui installation.

What could be the reason and how to solve this problem ?
here is the screenshot
http://s25.postimg.org/6uwnss067/debian7.jpg

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried booting into rescue mode?  It should be one of the options at boot time.

Comment: @Zoredache, have tried, no luck (((